# why can't tasks enqueued during transactions have names?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just learnt that transactional tasks cannot be named. Why is that? It's as though naming a task is an action on a different entity group, but "unnamed" tasks are actually given api-generated names.

Comment: And from where you learn that?? Can you provide a link?

Comment: manjoor: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Within_Transactions

"Transactional tasks must not have user-specified names."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Task names are unique, so if you add a task named "foo", subsequent adds of tasks named "foo" will fail. This check for uniqueness needs to be done within a transaction itself, so all named tasks in an application would have to have the same entity group.

If you're trying to atomically enqueue tasks within a transaction then the tasks will have to have the same entity group as the other entities in the transaction and uniqueness check would not be reliable.